# get a null object after used @autowired to DI

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-data-jpa

I have a utils class that use **@Autowired** to inject a repository using spring-boot-starter-data-jpa. But when I used this repository to access the database, it said the repository is null. I used the same method in my controller and it works well. And here is my **Utils.class**

```
package com.example.controller;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.dao.RuleRepository;
import com.example.model.Project;
import com.example.model.Rule;


public class Judge {

    @Autowired
    RuleRepository ruleRepository;

    public  boolean ageJudge(Project project) {
        try {

            if (ruleRepository == null) 
            {
                System.out.println("yes");
            }else {
                System.out.println("false");
            }

            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my **Application.java**

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example"})
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is the **RuleRepository.java**

```
package com.example.dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.example.model.Project;
import com.example.model.Rule;

public interface RuleRepository extends JpaRepository<Rule, Integer>{
    Rule findById(Integer id);
    Rule findByRuleName(String ruleName);

}
```

It is the directory.
[image]

The RuleRepository works well in controller. So, what is the problem?

Comment: I can not see where `Judge` is instanciated, but it doesn't look like an spring managed bean, so autowiring will not work

Comment: Please if you ask a question add always the stacktarce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your util class `Judge` is a plain POJO not a Spring bean and you can only inject Spring beans inside another Spring beans not Plain POJOs.

If you wish to use your `ruleRepository` bean inside `Judge` then make it a Spring component using `@Component` annotation:

```
@Component
public class Judge {

    @Autowired
    RuleRepository ruleRepository;

    .............................. 
}
```

User `@Service` annotation of `Judge` class is acting as business logic implementation class.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Judge` should be annotated @Component

```
@Component
public class Judge{
    // ...
}
```

so that Spring will instantiate a `Judge` bean and it will be available for injection. You can then use that judge bean in any managed bean (e.g: a controller)

```
// SomeController
@Autowired
Judge judge;
```

But if you instantiate judge object your self, like this:

```
Judge judge2 = new Judge();
```

your repository will be null, be cause Spring have nothing to do with judge2 object, it is not managed by Spring.

Comment: Yes, I just use  `Judge judge2 = new Judge();`   to create the Judge object. After goole about **@Controller**. I find it already extended the **Component**, so they work well in my controller.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your `Judge` class at least a `@Component` of your project, which will make your class managed by Spring, therefore your `RuleRepository` will be instantiated.

If it doesn't work on first try, you will have to add your `com.example.controller` package in the list of packages to scan, in the `@ComponentScan` annotation

Answer (score 0):

First as everyone mention your class Judge does not have `@Component` annotations.

The other thing is, maybe my Spring is getting little bit rusty.
But as far as I remember, I think your repository also require to have `@Component` or `@Repository` annotation